# Exectuting plugin as batch process in qGIS

Tags: python, plugins, batch-processing, qgis

I've been able to use the Qtile plugin in qGIS to generate an *.mbtile raster for the extent of a shapefile.
What I want to do is write a script, or create a tool in qGIS that allows me to point to a directory, and make an *.mbtile raster for every shapefile in the directory.
Like, I know this should be possible using python, but I have no idea how to get started.

What I want to be able to do is write a script that calls a plugin, changes the parameters, executes the plug in, and does it again with new parameters.

Comment: Did you succeed?

Comment: No. I also haven't returned to the issue in a while. The bummer is that while QGIS has some great and useful plugins, its not easy to adapt the plugins to a scripting environment.